# Air testing for new plumbing in addition?

Tags: plumbing, testing

I have inspection in a few days for my new plumbing (3" SCH 40), 1 1/2" Drain lines. Inspector told me I am responsible for the test plugs, air guage and the whole set up. Im looking to set this up the best way. Any recommendations?

I have my floor flange to the toilet installed and my 3" connected and it runs across to pick up the 1 1/2" drains then goes outside my wall. So I'll need to plug the 1 1/2" drains which I picked up the test caps, they (Lowes) told me to glue them in for the air test then just cut the pipe off near the end to get rid of the test cap since it is glued in.

Also, any opinions, suggestions for my 1/2" cpvc water feed lines. How do they get tested? Air or just water supply fed to them?

Thank you in advance to any answers. Appreciate it.

Comment: They sell test plugs, that fit in the pipe and expand to seal. Then there's no gluing or cutting involved. Run a Google search for 'test plug', you should find something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/c1/c19691aa-771b-4b04-855c-1186f0f06f3e_300.jpg). They are available in many sizes.

Comment: Hi tester101, yes thank you. I had seen them at Lowes. About 4 bucks for 3". I am more in need of setting this up to put the air in the lines. I have the air compressor here but just need to get the line ready for air. Any certain way I can do that. I need the air guage and a way for the inspector to put air in the line. The local plumbing shop told me some guys use rubber fernco's to go from the pipe size down to the air guage with the air valve. Seems like an easier, more common way to do it. Any suggestions?